# How to find the FQDN of an Azure VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure, ssh, virtual-machine

I just spun up a new Azure VM from the portal. I want to find the FQDN of the said portal so that I can connect to it via SSH, using this scheme: `ssh username@FQDN -p 22` Can anyone tell me where to look? I've spent many hours trying to do this, but to no avail.

Comment: Is this a resource manager VM? (i.e. v2) or a classic VM (v1) are you looking in the portal? or the old portal?- We need a little more information first...

Comment: So this is essentially a Postgresql DB I spun up in a docker container via "Container Apps". It shows up in my **Virtual Machines** list, not my **Virtual Machines (classic)** list. I'm trying to migrate my app from Heroku to Azure, and trying to trouble shoot some issues I'm running into along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you to get your FQDN on azure you should execute on Linux:

`hostname -f`

this will give you the name of the machine to see how you connect to the machine you need to be inside the same network. or if you are outside the network you need to look at the IP of the machine, not the machine FQDN and on the IP of the machine, you can see the DNS settings. to verify what are the IPs that you have if you are using version 2 you can go to this URL:
https://portal.azure.com/?l=en#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResourceBlade/resourceType/Microsoft.Network%2FPublicIpAddresses/scope/

Comment: You say that if I'm outside the networking, I have to give the IP of the machine, meaning my ssh command becomes `ssh username@IP`? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

On a windows azure vm; you need to be logged into the machine you want to find the FQDN

1. Use `ipconfig` to find your ip.
2. `ping -a IP`. The "-a" switch returns the domain name of your server. It will be in the first line.